# Matrix levels extraction

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

The matrix with which I am working is binary and is quite large: 2000 x 210 million.

For specific columns I need to check the proportion of values set to 1. Currently I am doing (`ind` is the index of columns where it should be checked, `mat` is the matrix, and `w` is where results are stored):

```
for(i in 1:length(ind){
which(mat[,ind[i]==1)->k
length(k)/2000->w[i,1]
}
```

`mat` is already a big matrix but it already takes 20-30 seconds and I need to process much larger matrices. How can I speed up this operation?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
colMeans(mat)
```

## Data

```
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace=T), 100)

w <- colMeans(mat)
w
[1] 0.51 0.47 0.43 0.54 0.50 0.47 0.48 0.50 0.49 0.55
```

## Update

User-defined columns:

```
means.func <- function(m, ind) {
  colMeans(m[,ind])
}
means.func(mat, 3:10)
[1] 0.43 0.54 0.50 0.47 0.48 0.50 0.49 0.55
```